# How to remove shadow from glyphicons in bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a bootstrap carousel on my site.  The right and left arrow glyphicons which come with it are surrounded by a square grey box of shading.  I was wondering if someone could tell me how to remove the shading so I just have the arrows.  Do I have to overwrite bootstrap's css somehow?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've had this issue before, just add this as bootstrap offers the shadow as a background image or/and as a filter

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
   background-image:none !important;
   filter:none !important;
}
```

And as suggested before i would change the opacity, but to 1

Answer (score 1):

just add `<style="background-image: none;">` in .carousel control

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're referring to is the .carousel-control items.

This Bootply that I've created should show you what you need to adjust which is the opacity of the element.

http://www.bootply.com/TvRdyXhIxo

Set the opacity to on the normal state and the hover state to whatever you want.

```
.carousel-control {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this and make sure it's overwrite the bootstrap.css

```
.carousel-control {
    background-image:none !important;
    filter:none !important;
}
```